# RequireJs - using jQuery UI with a private-jquery.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs

I am using a private jquery as described in the documentaiton.

jquery-private.js

```
define(['jquery'], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

My config file looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
        'jquery.ui.core': 'lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.core',
        'jquery.ui.widget': 'lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.widget',
        'jquery.ui.datepicker': 'lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker',
        'jquery-private': 'lib/jquery-private'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.ui.core': {
             deps: ['jquery'] 
        },        
        'jquery.ui.widget': {
             deps: ['jquery.ui.core'] 
        },        
        'jquery.ui.datepicker': {
              deps: ['jquery.ui.widget'] 
        },    
    },
    map: {
        '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-private' },
        'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
      }    
});

requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

Everything works except jquery-ui, it crashes internally because `$ is undefined` as it is no longer exported to the global scope.

```
define(['page/lib/address', 'jquery', 'jquery.ui.datepicker'], function(address, $) {

    $( "#my-date" ).datepicker(); //crashes here
});
```

Is it possible to use jquery-ui when jquery is private?